# Python slicing output

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a school project on analyzing logs & roughly, I need to be able to retrieve the day & time from a line in the format "*MM DD HH:MM:SS*" and it always shows as "*['MM DD HH:MM:SS']*"

```
def get_complete_date(line):
    """ 
    Pre : line est une ligne de log bien formée (str)
    Post : Retourne la date et l'heure sous forme de chaine de caractère sans changer le format.
    """
    # splt = line.split(sep=" ", maxsplit=5)
    # dt = splt[2] 
    

    complete_date = line.split(" ")
    
    # print(complete_date)

    return complete_date[0:3]
```

Comment: `line.split(" ")` returns a list object.

Comment: could you add an example of log line?

Comment: Add examples of the input and expected output, the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive approach, but if the length of datetime part is the same (same pattern on each line), you can simply slice it from 0 to pattern length:

```
def get_complete_date(l):
    tpl = "MM DD HH:MM:SS"
    return l[0: len(tpl)]

line = "MM DD HH:MM:SS some text"

print(get_complete_date(line))
>>>'MM DD HH:MM:SS'
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost there. It's an issue with slicing.

```
def get_complete_date(line):
    """
    Pre : line est une ligne de log bien formée (str)
    Post : Retourne la date et l'heure sous forme de chaine de caractère sans changer le format.
    """
    # splt = line.split(sep=" ", maxsplit=5)
    # dt = splt[2]


    complete_date = line.split(" ")

    # print(complete_date)

    return complete_date[1:3:1]

line = "MM DD HH:MM:SS"

print(get_complete_date(line))
```

Gives #

```
['DD', 'HH:MM:SS']
```

Explanation: Your slicing should be

```
[1:3:1] = [start:stop:step]
```

The *0th element is month* which you don't need to start from `1`.

Comment: What does you mean by *"Gives #"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Gives# means If you run the code it gives# output as